found an invalid expression token in terraform
i have list of value parsing into create a new list of data values. i have shared the below information. when i was plan, got an error message is
│ Error: Invalid expression
│
│   on main.tf line 155, in locals:
│  155:   api_sqs =
│  156:     [
│
│ Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
╵

In xx.tfvars
sqs_ls = ["raw-xxx-xxxxx","aaaaa","sssss","ddddd","fffff"]

base_path = "/asd-a/v1"

In main.tf
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}


locals {
  sqs_arn_pattern="arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:sqs:path/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
   api_gateway_name = "${var.Customer_Code}-${var.Environment_Code}-${var.Environment_ID_Code}-${var.Product_Code}-${var.Region_Code}-${var.Availability_Zone_Code}"
    sqs_lss = var.sqs_ls
  api_sqs =
    [
      for i, ii in local.sqs_lss : "{${var.base_path}/${ii} = { post = ${local.sqs_arn_pattern}/${ii}}}"
       ]
}

output "ll" {
  value = local.api_sqs
}



Just a guess: "{${var.base_path}/${ii} = { post = ${local.sqs_arn_pattern}/${ii}}}" should be {"${var.base_path}/${ii}" = { post = "${local.sqs_arn_pattern}/${ii}"}}. Or something similar.

The Terraform language uses newline as the delimiter between arguments in a block, so Terraform understands api_sqs = as an argument whose expression starts with a newline character and that is invalid.
If you place the bracket on the same line as the attribute name and the equals sign then it should parse correctly:
  api_sqs = [
    for i, ii in local.sqs_lss : "{${var.base_path}/${ii} = { post = ${local.sqs_arn_pattern}/${ii}}}"
  ]

Between the [ and ] brackets Terraform is parsing in expression context rather than in argument context, so newline characters are not significant there and it's fine (but not required) to introduce a newline character before the for keyword.
